# How can I give permission for PUT and DELETE in openam

Tags: liferay-6, alfresco, openam

I integrate openam. If PUT and DELETE service execute then got 
**403 Forbidden error**
How can i give access or permission to execute PUT and DELETE service in openam?

Which configuration file i have change?

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

OpenAM 12 (or later) supports other REST verbs (DELETE, PUT, etc.) in the policy editor. For previous versions you have to do this manually. Upgrading is recommended.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds that you are attempting to use the OpenAM Restful API to delete a user account.  Many of OpenAM Restful APIs need to have the iPlanetDirectoryPro cookie in the header of the request.  In the case of deleting a user's account, the iplanetDirectoryPro cookie should be a session cookie of the openam administrator.  In this example I used the session cookie of the amadmin.

```
curl --request DELETE \
--header "iplanetDirectoryPro: AQIC5wM2L...EzMzAz*" \
http://openam.example.com:8080/openam/json/users/demouser
```

The following is the response from that request:`{"success":"true"}`